# Can the "ancient doom" prophecy be completed with the weapon in the secondary slot?

Tags: path-of-exile

The "Ancient Doom" prophecy states

> You will defeat the Vaal Oversoul while wielding Doomfletch.

The problem is that I got it on Merciless, and Doomfletch is quite underpowered for that level.

Can I equip Doomfletch in the secondary weapon slot (i.e., the non active one) and still complete the prophecy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can weapon swap right before it dies though. Ignites, poisons, or decay make it pretty easy to pull off.